# Skip Jackrabbit login prompt

Tags: http, authentication, jackrabbit

I have a standalone JackRabbit repository. 
It is populated via RMI using some credentials (write access). 
Read access by HTTP is enabled to any credentials (by default).

One of the use cases is to generate URL links to repository items (files) on a JSP page, so that users could click them to view in browser or download. The links are generated, but upon clicking them we get a 403 error. If that link is copy-pasted to another browser tab, it asks for login/password and displays (or downloads) the file.

I had an idea about passing some (possibly empty) login/password to URL, like this:

```
http://user:password@host:port/blahblah
```

But it is not allowed for HTTP by RFC (though it works sometimes, not always, and that doesn't suit me)

The question is, how to remove login/password prompt for HTTP access? It seems redundant, because any credentials allow read access. Can it be configured in repository.xml, security.xml or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` deployment descriptor inside the Jackrabbit webapp. The `<servlet>` configuration entry for the SimpleWebdavServlet contains the `missing-auth-mapping` option that's commented out by default:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>missing-auth-mapping</param-name>
     <param-value>anonymous:anonymous</param-value>
     <description>
         Defines how a missing authorization header should be handled.
         1) If this init-param is missing, a 401 response is generated.
            This is suitable for clients (eg. webdav clients) for which
            sending a proper authorization header is not possible if the
            server never sent a 401.
         2) If this init-param is present with an empty value,
            null-credentials are returned, thus forcing an null login
            on the repository.
         3) If this init-param is present with the value 'guestcredentials'
            java.jcr.GuestCredentials are used to login to the repository.
         4) If this init-param has a 'user:password' value, the respective
            simple credentials are generated.
     </description>
 </init-param>
```

Enabling this parameter should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This was not commented out in standalone Jackrabbit jar, actually. Anyway...

I've set the param-value to all described kinds of values (empty , guestcredentials, 1:1, anonymous:anonymous, ...), and it still keeps asking login/password. Looks like this parameter says what to use if no login/password were specified, but doesn't prohibit from asking it.

Comment: @manuna I know this is too late for you, but for the benefit of others: I too was caught by this - turns out there are two servlets that accept this parameter, and the one where the parameter comes declared by default is the 'JCRWebdavServer' (JcrRemotingServlet) servlet, but you want to declare the parameter under the 'Webdav' (SimpleWebdavServlet) servlet.